# calling ng-view controller method from outside controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="san">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="sanctrl">
<div>
    AngularJS</div>
<div ng-view="">
</div>
<button type="button" ng-click="init()" class="btn btn-blue">
    Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Main Controller:

```
san.controller('sanctrl', function ($scope, $http, $q, $location, $anchorScroll, $filter, dataFactory) {
//nothing in this controller.
});
```

ng-view controller:

```
san.app.controller('cereals', function ($scope, dataFactory) {
  $scope.init(){
    $scope.test = "test";
  };
});
```

I am trying to call init method from outside ng-view scope. Is it possible? if not then what are the options we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a broadcast event that you trigger:

```
  $rootScope.$broadcast('testEvent', testArray);
```

Then in 2nd controller you can listen for the event:

```
  $scope.$on('testEvent', function(event, array) {

      // Do stuff here

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

As @lulu88 you can do using `$broadcast` other than that

write a seperate service move the code in `int()`  function to that , then you can acess that from any controller